# Reverse not found even if the name was set correctly Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, view

I have a view for a product liking like this below:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def LikeView(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=pk)
    product.bumps.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detailcreate', args=[pk]))
```

but when I am sending a post request like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/like/04a544c1-78a2-4dc7-9b1c-897feb527541
```

I get an error: `Reverse for 'detailcreate' not found. 'detailcreate' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

My urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import LikeView, ProductList, ProductDetail

app_name = 'name'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<uuid:pk>', ProductDetail.as_view(), name='detailcreate'),
    path('', ProductList.as_view(), name='listcreate'),
    path('like/<uuid:pk>', LikeView, name='like_product'),
]
```

so I don't know what is wrong, the name is corectlly set.

pk is `uuid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `app_name` you should specify it when resolving url:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('name:detailcreate', args=[pk]))
```